# Optimising exponential function in java

Tags: java, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Hello currently I am trying to program a calculator with java and have a small problem with optimizing my exponential function. The Exponential function is using the Taylor theorem and my question is are there a better way then do the factorial for every iteration?

```
    public static BigDecimal exp(BigDecimal x){
    
    int b = 0;
    while(x.abs().compareTo(BigDecimal.TEN.pow(b, mc)) >= 0) {
        b++;
    }
    BigDecimal a = x.divide(BigDecimal.TEN.pow(b, mc), mc);
    BigDecimal r = new BigDecimal("0");
    BigDecimal k = new BigDecimal("0");
    BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal(E);
    
    
    while(e.divide(factorial(k.add(BigDecimal.ONE, mc)), mc).compareTo(epsilon)>=0){
        r = r.add(a.pow(k.intValue(), mc).divide(factorial(k), mc), mc);
        k = k.add(BigDecimal.ONE, mc);
    }
    while(b > 0)
    {
        r = r.pow(10, mc);
        b--;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: At each iteration, it looks like you are simply adding 1 to `k`. Computing the factorial of `k` for the next iteration can be made much more efficient by simply storing the previous factorial value and multiplying by the incremented `k` value.

Comment: @Ted Hopp thank you very much for the answer! Such a simple and more efficient way.